# Передача параметров с тремя точками в функцию в Go

Tags: golang

```
func example(c string, args ...string) {
    exec.Command(c, args)
}
```

выдает ошибку

```
cannot use args (type []string) as type string
```

Почему? Почему нельзя передать в качестве аргумента неопределенную строку в виде конструкции `...string`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Когда у вас уже готовый слайс, его надо "распределить":

```
exec.Command(c, args...)
```

Об этом написано в [Effective Go](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#printing):

> Within the function Printf, v acts like a variable of type []interface{} but if it is passed to another variadic function, it acts like a regular list of arguments. Here is the implementation of the function log.Println we used above. It passes its arguments directly to fmt.Sprintln for the actual formatting.
>
> ```
> // Println prints to the standard logger in the manner of fmt.Println.
> func Println(v ...interface{}) {
>     std.Output(2, fmt.Sprintln(v...))  // Output takes parameters (int, string)
> }
> ```
>
> We write ... after v in the nested call to Sprintln to tell the compiler to treat v as a list of arguments; otherwise it would just pass v as a single slice argument.